# How to remove extra width of text which is coming from parent?

Tags: css

I have a CSS problem I need help solving.

I have an `ul` for showing a column. I've hardcoded the width of this `ul` to 220px. Inside it, I have `li`'s. Each `li` has a text link.

Problem is, because I have hardcoded the `ul` width to 220px, the `li` are inheriting this, even though they don't need so much width. If I see the space each `li` text is taking, this is what I see:

[image]

How can I make each `li` text ONLY take as much space as it needs for the text itself ?

I want to do this because I have a picture in the background which has a map on it .. The extra space taken by `li`'s means that the map isn't working in areas where it should work (because `li`'s are on top of the map) ..

Answer (score 1):

Use `display:inline-block;` Or `display:inline;`.

Or:

Use `float:left;` on each `li` then have a `clear:both;` element after each `li`.

Comment: I am trying that, but it's somehow messing up the spacing in my display .. Is there some alternative approach ?

Comment: Problem is because they're inline now, multiple li's are now showing in same line, whenever the sum of their individual widths is lesser than 220px .. It makes sense, but how do I avoid this from happening ? clear:both doesn't seem to work.

Comment: You could try and just set a width? @Ahmad

Comment: Or a `max-width` @Ahmad

Comment: Nah, thats not practical for me because there are a lot of different text lengths here ..

Answer (score 0):

You can use  `display:inline-block;`

Comment: I am trying that, but it's somehow messing up the spacing in my display .. Is there some alternative approach ? Problem is because they're inline now, multiple li's are now showing in same line, whenever the sum of their individual widths is lesser than 220px .. It makes sense, but how do I avoid this from happening ? clear:both doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

add `float:left` to your `<li>`s.
& put a `<div style="clear:both;"></div>` after each.